# SkiaSharp SKSvg.Load throws MissingMethodException

Tags: xamarin, svg, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I use SkiaSharp libraries on my Xamarin.Core/Xamarin.iOS project.
I try to load an SVG file from the Core library like the following;

```
 var svg = new SKSvg();

 Assembly assembly = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

 using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Images.watermark_light.svg"))
 {
     svg.Load(stream);
 }
```

The code throws on the "Load" step saying **"System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: SkiaSharp.SKTextBlob SkiaSharp.SKTextBlob.CreatePositioned(string,SkiaSharp.SKFont,System.ReadOnlySpan`1<SkiaSharp.SKPoint>)"**

**My configuration:**

- Device: Debug|Simulator
- Linker Behaviour: Don't link
- Xamarin.iOS 15.4.0.0
- xcode13.2: 8fc41ae82
- Rider IDE: RD-221.5591.20
- OS: MacOS Monterey 12.4 (21F79)

*Libraries*

- SkiaSharp v2.88.1-preview.79
- SkiaSharp.Views v2.88.1-preview.79
- Svg.Skia v0.5.14
- SkiaSharp.Svg v1.60.0
- CoreLibrary/Images/watermark_light.svg(svg path)

I tried to add SKTextBlob reference to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs as well. But, it should not be the case when the linker behaviour is set to "Don't link". Also a added --linkskip argument for the relevant namespace. None of them worked. Any ideas about the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps an inconsistency between versions of those libraries. Carefully check the nuget page for each one, to see what they say about version dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to version 0.5.16 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg.Skia/0.5.16

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the trick. Interestingly, I thought I was on the latest versions of each library, but I wasn't.

Comment: @T.Y.Kucuk I have release that version very recently